# erro ao passar variaveis num controller

Tags: laravel, controller, dompdf

Bom dia programadores ,
Estou com um problemas ao passar duas variaveis de uma funçao para outra , penso eu.
A baixo segue-se o Código

```
class pdfController extends Controller
{
    public function index($id)
    {
        $service = $this->get_service_data($id);
        return view('services.pdf')->with('service',$service);
    }
    public function get_service_data($id)
    {
        $service = Service::find($id);
        $materials=$service->mats_por_servicos = DB::table('mats_por_servicos as mats_serv')
            ->join('materials as material','mats_serv.mat_id','=','material.id')
            ->where('serv_id',$id)
            ->get();

        return [$service,$materials];
    }
    public function pdf()
    {
        $pdf =\App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
        $pdf->loadHTML($this->convert_service_to_html());

    }
    public function convert_service_to_html($id)
    {
        $service = $this->get_service_data($id);
    }

}
```

erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está passando para sua view um array, mas está tentando acessar como se fosse um objeto. Sua variável `service` na view será `[$service, $materials]`, então provavelmente você precisa fazer `service[0]` para acessar o objeto que deseja.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, notamos que o erro esta sendo reportando na sua view ao acessar o service->designation, neste caso na view faça um DD para analisar como este objeto esta chegando na view:

Na View:

**{{ dd($service) }}**

Assim vocẽ vai poder analisar o modelo e os dados do objeto.